# How to derive BTC m44 addresses from xpub?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, address-generation

I checked **Swan's Address Derivation Library** https://github.com/swan-bitcoin/xpub-tool.

I try to get `m44` address, but I got `m84`. Why? Do you know is it any parameter to force return `m44`? I tried to pass `path: "m/44'/0'/0'/0",` but it did not help.

Do you have any idea?

```
addressFromXPub("xpub6C5oXscLYZwgq2DB42TFC32QcoPa1MeCWUNPZSjydunniCM77TRcBfFnjScJeToVXS5RBDr53Ls5RXvDHujmFSL4Fqc9kkpsMjU1vg68xv7"
  );

export const addressFromXPub = (key) => {
  console.log(
    addressesFromExtPubKey({
      extPubKey: key,
      network: "mainnet",
      addressCount: 3,
    })
  );
};
```

```
[
    {path: "m/84'/0'/0'/0/0", address: "bc1qfgnqm6g46ys0h9gh606m76wemka2rrttrac90x"
    },
    {path: "m/84'/0'/0'/0/1", address: "bc1qnvzdj2m4wsrcrtl30j5c304qa77v4h2s8ajp0r"
    },
    {path: "m/84'/0'/0'/0/2", address: "bc1qjf5u77e6clwkxgf7a0shw7zq2nhqr4vjys7an0"
    }
]
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to pass the derivation path as m/44'/0'/0'/0? I don't see it in your question. Also, xpubs already have the derivation path encoded in them. You can't change an xpub's deriv without changing the root and then create a new xpub/ypub/zpub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following key:

```
xpub6C5oXscLYZwgq2DB42TFC32QcoPa1MeCWUNPZSjydunniCM77TRcBfFnjScJeToVXS5RBDr53Ls5RXvDHujmFSL4Fqc9kkpsMjU1vg68xv7
```

Corresponds to a level 3 public key w/index of 0x00000080 which is 0h/0'. In the context you've described it *probably* corresponds to "m/?/?/**0'**". This key's parent's fingerprint is 0x3ab9169c, so you'd need to provide the parent's full fingerprint to confirm the original derivation path.

Although m44 & m84 have the same master/root key, they have completely different level 1 keys, which would change all lower nodes. In short you can only derive m/... full paths from root keys, not child keys, which you've provided.

Edit: The key you've provided is probably meant for deriving receive & change addresses of a certain address type.

Comment: thanks, do you know here: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ which field contains the root keys? I tried both: `Account Extended Public Key` and `BIP32 Extended Public Key` to pass to `addressesFromExtPubKey`, but again m84 was returned, strange